# How can I install java on a raspberry pi running kali linux

Tags: pi-3, java, kali

I am trying out kali Linux on my raspberry pi for the first time, and I am trying to install java, as I use it a lot on my pi.  I didn’t want to give this up because of my new os.  However, when I try to install java using “apt-get install oracle-java7-jdk”, I get the error:

```
Package openjdk-7-jdk is not available but is referred to by another package.This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source E: Unable to locate package openjdk-7-jdk
```

I can’t find a solution anywhere, so help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you Googled "install java on kali Linux"? I did and it gave some helpful looking results. I haven't tried any, but you should before you ask here, and tell us how they fail if they don't work.

Answer (score 2):

First point is Kali Linux comes preloaded with all languages like C, C++, and Java.

To check, try the following command in terminal:

```
java -version
```

If it shows the Java information then Java is already installed on your system. If it is not, then simply use this command:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

It will install Java on your system.

Comment: The OP wants to use something that needs oracle-java7-jdk.

Comment: Judging from the title, I think more likely the OP just didn't realize he could install Java 8+ instead.